# C# + mysql I want to select 1000 rows then update those selected rows

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I am going to have multiple processes running at the same time so what I tried to do here is fetch 1000 rows and then update the rows i selected.. below are my Select and Update functions notice i call the update function right after closing the connection in the select function

```
    public List<string> Select()
    {
        string set;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM master WHERE attempted='0' LIMIT 1000";
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (list.Count() < 1000)
            {
                dataReader.Read();
                string email = dataReader["email"].ToString();              
                var m = dataReader["attempted"];
                if (m.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    list.Add(email);

                }                  
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
            Update();
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }





    public void Update()
    {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
                string query = "UPDATE master SET attempted='1' WHERE ( SELECT * FROM master WHERE attempted='0' LIMIT 1000 )";              
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

the exception i am getting it operand must contain 1 column(s)..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could be put in a book as an example "don't do this"...

Comment: Andres use parameterized query for starters also why don't you pass parameters to the Update Method this way you can change your UPDATE Master statement to `UPDATE master SET attempted = '1' Where @EmailAddress = email and attempted =0` something like that.. you do not need a SUB Select on this particular UPDATE Statement

Comment: When you utilize the update Query you generally associate it with the value you'd like to be changed; then create a sub-query that will find the desired criteria to be altered. Your particular method is going against the structure.

Comment: i was doing something like that before but it took a really long time to update the 1000 rows. is there any way to do it faster than running 1000 queries?

Comment: Create an Async request that utilizes lazy loading; that way your application doesn't halt and appears to be doing items for the user.  Or don't do 1,000 rows at once.

Comment: Yeah refactor your query for starter Andres.. if you are not sure you should run an execution Plan or have a DBA optimize this query.. better yet .. why not have this done as an optimized stored procedure..?

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Just about everything its would appear. Question. Given you arent using it in update, why did you post the select function? If you want to do a 1,000 at a time (why?) you could do it all in sql.

Comment: Good call Kraze, running at the Query level may be fastest.  As it can pull multiple rows / modify them very quickly. What are you trying to do? Modify an email address?

Comment: I have a program that is going to be pulling email addresses from a database.. Since I am going to have multiple programs running simultaneously I want the program to get a list of 1000 email addresses and change the attempted column to 1 that way no other program gets those emails.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just create a separate column, or even a table?  Then write a basic Query at the SQL level or a Procedure to modify the value? Then the other applications can just test the value of the column or table.

Example:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]
SET [GotEmail] = 1
WHERE (
       SELECT [Email]
       FROM [dbo].[Customer]
       );
```

Or something basic like that?  Another example would be:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET (contact_last_name, contact_first_name) = 
    (SELECT last_name, first_name FROM salesmen
WHERE salesmen.id = accounts.sales_id);
```

Does a simple query like so not solve your issue?

If my response is not clear...  I'll try and clarify my thought process.